# Issues installing Sitecore Rocks on VS Express 2013

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

I'm not able to install `sitecore rocks` in my VS Express 2013. Im getting the error "`This extension is not able install on my currently installed products`"
I downloaded the file from [this link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44a26c88-83a7-46f6-903c-5c59bcd3d35b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the supported versions of VS:

http://vsplugins.sitecore.net/Supported-Visual-Studio-Versions.ashx

> Sitecore Rocks only works with Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 (and maybe later versions).
>
> Only Visual Studio Premium, Proffesional and Ultimation editions are supported.

Visual Studio Express is not supported.

Comment: (and maybe later versions) :D

Comment: @SilentTremor What I pasted is official statement. But you're absolutely right - newer versions may be possibly supported as well :)

Comment: It really has to do with the fact that Express editions of VS do not support plug-ins. Can't install Resharper on them either, for instance. Seems this restriction is gone for good on newer versions; VS2015 Community Edition (the free one) supports plugins and Rocks! works fine there.